# Apple Push Notification HTTP2 rejected token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, http2, pushy

I just found that some of my users stopped receiving push notification recently. Checked the log and found that Apple returned "Unregistered" with a timestamp.

I've tried using both old protocol and new HTTP/2 protocol with the same cert and token. The push using old protocol was received nicely, while the HTTP/2 one just returned "Unregistered".

The strange thing is not all my users failed, just some of them.

Anyone have idea on what's going on? Or face the same problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this problem rectified? What's status? Do you forced roll-back to old protocol?